# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') in react error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> i practice react
> but i facing some error I know this small error but I am beginner in react

**i trying to authentication firebase but i facing this error**

> When i sign in button press this type error comming

[image]

*`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`*

my app.js code

**app.js**

```
function App() {

  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState()

  return (
    <Router>
      <nav>
      <Link to="/login">login</Link>
      <Link to="/post">Create Post</Link>
      <Link to="/">home</Link>
    </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login setIsAuth={setIsAuth}/>} />
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/post" element={<CreatPost />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my login.js code

**login.js**

```
function Login({ setIsAuth }) {

  const singInGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(provider, auth).then((result) => {
      setIsAuth(true);
      localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>sign In with to google acount</p>
      <button onClick={singInGoogle}>sign In</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Can you please share the stacktrace of the error please? This JS error happens when you trying to read a property of an object but that object is actually null (basically, trying to read a property of a null variable. In this case, property `create`). I'm not founding any relationship with the snippets you're sharing and the actual error